# selectionSort method that'll sort an ArrayList by type

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, selection-sort

SOF. I have a problem which I'm having some difficulty with.

The following code is supposed to sieve through the file line-by-line, utilizes the StringTokenizer effectively to get the Car Class's Make, Model, Year, and Mileage (in that order) and store those in a car object, which I then add to 2 ArrayLists, one of which is "sorted" by Make and the other which is "unsorted".

The selectionSort I wrote initially worked with Strings which didn't work for obvious reasons.

Can this be fixed by making the selectionSort work with objects (Cars)? Eclipse recommended that to me and the current selectionSort is a product of that.

```
public void readFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException //an object array that takes in string files
{  
   try {
        File myFile = new File(file); //converts the parameter string into a file
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile); //File enables us to use Scanner
        String line = scanner.nextLine(); //reads the current line and points to the next one
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ","); //tokenizes the line, which is the scanned file

        int tokenCount = new StringTokenizer(line, ",").countTokens(); //counts the tokens 
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
            if(tokenCount > 4) {
               System.out.println(" Not 4 tokens");
            }
            else {
               String CarMake = tokenizer.nextToken(); //since car is in order by make, model, year, and mileage
               String CarModel = tokenizer.nextToken();
               int CarYear1 = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
               int CarMileage1 = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()); //converts the String numbers into integers
               Car cars = new Car(CarMake, CarModel, CarYear1, CarMileage1); //since the car has a fixed order 
               arraylist.add(cars); //add the cars to the unsorted array
            }
        }
        scanner.close(); //close the scanner  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException f){
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
    arraylist2.addAll(arraylist);
    selectionSort(arraylist2);
}

public static void selectionSort(ArrayList<Car> arraylist) //Selection sort using strings
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= arraylist.size(); i++)
  {
    // Look through the unsorted strings (those at j or higher) for the one that is first in order
    int min = i;
    for (arraylist[i].getMake.compareTo(arraylist[min].getMake) < 0) { //use the inherent string compareTo
          min = k;  
    }
    String temp = arraylist[i].getMake; //swapping
    arraylist[i].getMake = arraylist[min].getMake;
    arraylist[min] = temp;
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your new code doesn't work is that you're swapping only the makes of the Cars, not the full `Car` objects.

It should be:

```
Car temp = arraylist[i]; //swapping
arraylist[i] = arraylist[min];
arraylist[min] = temp;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but I'd also suggest you to use another sorting algorithm, if possible/allowed in your use-case. Selection-sort is one of the worse sorting algorithm, even though it's easy to implement.

Comment: Hm, what do you recommend?

Comment: So, something like Collections.sort(arraylist2, null);?? Would this work for sorting the Make objects in lexicographic order? Can this be used viably as an alternative to selectionSort?

Comment: Using `null` as second parameter won't work, as you need a Comparator that checks the make values. Supposed you have a getter method `getMake()` in your car class, you could use `List.sort(…)` with `Comparator.comparing(…)` and an expression lambda to extract the make from a Car object:

`arrayList2.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getMake));`

Comment: Also, I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer if it helped you with your issue.